# import error when i try to import lxml.html

Tags: python, html, windows, import, lxml

I received import error in the following code and I can't fix it

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
import urllib.request as url
import lxml.html
```

the error :

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\ORIB1\Downloads\PageRank-master (1)\PageRank-master\src\altparse\alt_htmlparser.py", line 4, in <module>
    import lxml.html
```

Answer (score 1):

What about install this package to interpreter or virtual environment?

Comment: Do you use global interpreter or virtual environment?